# Making A Javascript Function Available To Java Code

Tags: java, javascript

#### Problem Description

A somewhat contrived example to illustrate my question.  Imagine we have some library of javascript functions that is already maintained and updated daily by an army of frontend devs.  To be specific, imagine one such function looks like this:

```
function employeesForStore(store) {
    var dictionary = {
        "downtown": ["Joe", "Mary", "Steve"],
        "uptown": ["Jules", "Vincent", "Matt"],
        // and so on for hundreds of locations
    };
    return dictionary[store];
}
```

*NOTE:* Please ignore the details of this function's implementation.  The actual function may be far more complex than simple JSON dictionary lookups, and assume we don't know any implementation details about the js function.  All we know is it takes a String argument and returns and array of Strings.

Now we would like to take advantage of this function in our Java code.  That is, in our Java code, we'd like to "load" this function, and then be able to call it multiple times, passing it `String` args and receiving `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>` results.

From searching SO and google so far, I understand that this will involve using:

- `javax.script.ScriptEngineManager`
- `javax.script.ScriptEngine`
- and perhaps `scriptEngine.getContext()` for passing values into the function and receiving results.

I am a bit hazy on the details of the above, especially since most examples I've found involve running javascript code a single time, rather than making javascript function available to Java.

#### Example Code I'd Like To See

1. Assuming the js function is in the file "my_functions.js", load that file into Java so all of its functions will be available for use.
2. Call `employeesForStore("downtown")` and store its results in a native java `String[]` or `List<String>` in a variable called `downtownResults`.
3. Same as 2, but call `employeesForStore("uptown")` and store in variable `uptownResults`

Comment: In your case, you are just accessing a js object, which you can serialise to JSON, and parse it in Java.

Comment: @moonwave99, ignore the details of how `employeesForStore` is implemented.  We don't know that -- it was just a simple example for clarity.  In actuality, that function could be implemented totally differently inside, and might be far more complex than a simple JSON dictionary lookup.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7487908/how-i-can-use-javascript-in-java (they suggest Rhino as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an interface to act as a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to your JavaScript code.

Here is an example using the Rhino implementation embedded in Oracle's Java 1.7 implementation:

```
package demo;
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicReference;
import javax.script.*;

public class StoreData {
  public static interface Stores {
    public String[] employees(String store);
  }

  public static Stores stores() throws IOException, ScriptException {
    ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
    ScriptEngine engine = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
    AtomicReference<Stores> ref = new AtomicReference<>();
    engine.put("ref", ref);
    String adapt = "ref.set("
        + "new Packages.demo.StoreData.Stores({employees:employeesForStore})"
        + ");";
    try (Reader myFns = new FileReader("my_functions.js")) { // TODO encoding
      engine.eval(myFns);
      engine.eval(adapt);
      return ref.get();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ScriptException {
    List<String> employees = Arrays.asList(stores().employees("uptown"));
    System.out.println(employees);
  }
}
```

By specifying an interface we let Rhino coerce the JavaScript types to Java types (String, String[], etc.)

The JRE spec makes [no guarantees](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5943863/304) about what scripting engines should be provided so it may be wise to rely on an external engine. I don't know if [Nashorn](https://blogs.oracle.com/nashorn/entry/welcome_to_the_nashorn_blog) will change this.

Comment: Thanks for that!  Can you explain what's going on with `adapt`?  It looks like java code, but it's being eval'd by the JS engine.  Is it java or js? It appears the argument `{employees:employeesForStore}` is somehow mapping the java `employees` method to the js `employeesForStore` function -- is that correct?  How exactly is that happening?  Is `AtomicReference` responsible for the mapping, or something else?  +1 for great info already.

Comment: `Stores.employees` maps to `employeesForStore`. Rhino dynamically provides the `Stores` implementation - see [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Scripting_Java#Implementing_Java_Interfaces). The `AtomicReference` is just a way (not the only one) to grab a reference to the instance once it has been created. There's nothing special about the `AtomicReference` type in that regard.

Comment: Ok, so the JS script engine that we create is able to work with both java and js code interchangeably?

Comment: Yes, Rhino will generally coerce JavaScript types to Java types - e.g. [strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Scripting_Java#Java_Strings_and_JavaScript_Strings) - when it calls strongly typed Java methods.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Rhino API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) to execute JS code in java

This [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino/Embedding_tutorial#usingJSObjs) covers the examples requested.